# R > 4.1 equivalent to magrittr's aliases

Tags: r, magrittr

In R 4.1 introduced the native forward pipe (`|>`) that can be used instead of magrittr's `%>%`. For example,

```
c(1, 2, 3) |> length()
```

is a valid syntax in R > 4.1 and will return 3.

magrittr has a [collection of aliases](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/aliases.html). For example, instead of

```
1 * 2
```

I can write

```
1 %>% magrittr::multiply_by(2)
```

What are the R > 4.1 equivalent to magrittr's aliases?

Comment: Most of those listed aliases are not supported on the right hand side of the base R pipe. a general alias for it is to make a anonymous function such as `1 |> (\(.) . * 2)()` with the expression inside the function being anything you want. Note that if you make you [own aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847745/not-possible-to-use-special-functions-with-base-pipe-in-r) it does work.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the two pipes are *not exact equivalents* of each other.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such aliases are not provided by base but this works to multiply by 2.  The parentheses shown are required.

```
1:3 |> (`*`)(2)
```

It is also possible to use magrittr aliases with |>

```
library(magrittr)
1:3 |> multiply_by(2)
```

or to define an alias yourself

```
mult <- function(x, y) x * y
1:3 |> mult(2)
```

or

```
mult <- `*`
1:3 |> mult(2)
```

Another possibility is to find another way of expressing the same calculation.  In this case:

```
1:3 |> sapply(`*`, 2)
```